# Opencv Reading Multiple images from Multiple folder

Tags: opencv, matrix

I have a folder which contain 100 or more sub folders and each of them contain many images.(Caltech Database)

I have problem with how to read them from the different folders ?

I want to store them as a single matrix with stacking columms of each image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Boost Filesystem for C++. You can load all files in a directory and pass the file location to OpenCV in a string.

```
    string folder = "../images/";
    vector<string> imageFileLocations;
    namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
    vec v;
    copy(fs::directory_iterator(folder), fs::directory_iterator(), back_inserter(v));
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    for (vec::const_iterator it(v.begin()); it != v.end(); ++it) {
        if (fs::is_regular_file(*it)) {
            string location = it->string();
            imageFileLocations.push_back(location);
        }
    }
```

You'll have to add something recursive to be able to go into other folders. You can do that by checking if the iteraotr is at a file or a folder. See the [Boost website](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm) for examples.

Comment: Thanks,I have used back_inserter to do the recursive thing.It works well.